# How to Redirect URL on Google Sites

Tags: javascript, html, web, google-sites, sites

Okay, so I have a Google Site that I need to redirect to a website.
So for example, I have `sites.google.com/xxx/xxx`
And when people enter that, I want it to redirect to my website

```
www.xxxxxxxx.com
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could bypass this by using js to change href of some hidden  element and than use javascript to "click" on this element.
I've used this to create contacts search element directly on sites.

Markup

```
<a href="" id="searchHelper"></a>
<button onclick="functionSearch()" id="buttonSearch"> 
<input type="text" id="inputSearch" value="" placeholder="Search">
```

Javascript

```
      function functionSearch() {
        var inputSearch = document.getElementById("inputSearch");
        if (inputSearch.value != "") {
            document.getElementById("searchHelper").href = "https://contacts.google.com/search/" + inputSearch.value;
            document.getElementById("searchHelper").click();
        }
      }
```

Comment: this do not work for me app in browser. =\

Answer (score -1):

On App Script it's not possible.

In App Script , you can do this:

```
 var anchor = app.createAnchor("link", "http://www.google.com");
```

Look the doc :
=> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/anchor

On javascript :

```
//  click on a link
window.location.href = "http://google.com";
// redirect
window.location.replace("http://google.com");
```